# How to add scalable graphics on map using Open Layers 3?

Tags: image, svg, openlayers, openlayers-3

I am using OpenLayers (OL3) to display shapes and objects on a map.

The shapes represents buildings and will have a image resource either in SVG or PNG. I need to place this images with proper scale and rotation on the map and still being able to zoom/pan.

I have found a really good example using OpenLayers 2 here:
http://gis.ibbeck.de/ginfo/apps/OLExamples/OL27/examples/ExternalGraphicOverlay/ExternalGraphicOverlay.asp

I have problems converting this into OL3 (which I need for map rotation). 
The thing I got stuck is this (example code in OL2):

```
var context = {
   getW : function(){
     return theWidth * theResolution / map.getResolution();
   },
   getH : function(){
     return theHeight * theResolution / map.getResolution();
   },
   getR : function(){
     return theRotation;
   }
};
var template = {
   graphicWidth   : "${getW}",
   graphicHeight  : "${getH}",
   rotation       : "${getR}"
};
var styleMap = OpenLayers.Style(template, {context: context});
vectorLayer.styleMap = styleMap;
```

I don't find how to transform this into a ol.style.Style to set an image on the layer that scales on zoom.

How can this be accomplished using OL3?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [ol.source.ImageStatic](http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/static-image.html) ([API documentation](http://ol3js.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.source.ImageStatic.html)) is what you are looking for?

Comment: I have looked at that, but I find no examples of how to use it together with tiled layer. I want a real map in the background and buildings placed on top.

Now I am using ol.style.Icon and that works ok for rotation since I can set rotateWithView:true and scale gets refreshed after zoom change, but i would want it to scale during zoom/rotation too.